# The connection string 'mongodb//localhost' is not valid

Tags: mongodb, connection

Followed [Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) on how to connect to local host. **MongodDB Compass** can connect to "localhost:27017", no authentication, no SSL, no SSH Tunnel. In C# project, tried

```
mongodb//localhost
mongodb//localhost:27017
localhost:27017
```

all getting the same

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConfigurationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=The connection string 'all-above' is not
>   valid.   Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core   StackTrace:
>          at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString.Parse()
>          at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString)
>          at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse(String url)
>          at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor(String url)
>          at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(String connectionString)

Here is the code:

```
static string con = "mongodb//localhost";
MongoClient mclient = new MongoClient(con);
```

MongoDB.Driver v2.4.2, MongoDB.Driver.Core v2.4.2

What's wrong?

Comment: You miss the `:` separator. May be you need port too. Change to `"mongodb://localhost:27017"` More here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/connecting/#connection-string

Comment: @Veeram You are right. I knew there must be something stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- The " : " is missing after **mongodb** .
- In case if you're running on default port, just **mongodb://localhost** or **mongodb://localhost:27017**
  will do the job.
- In localhost but on a different port, then **mongodb://localhost:diff_port_num**
- In case if you have configured it to other port or mongo server is
  running on a different server in network the format looks something
  like this:  **mongodb://192.168.0.xx:27017**

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the port number on which MongoDB is running like,

**mongodb://localhost:27017**

I am using MongoDB 6.0 latest current Version.

The default port number which MongoDB uses is 27017. You can mention the same port number if you are running the MongoDB on same Port number.

You can verify the port number using mongod.cfg file on the line
**# network interfaces
net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 27.0.0.1**

If you have configured MongoDB for remote access then you need to mention the IP of server instead of localhost in connection string. also you need to mention the username and password of the user who is going to access the MongoDB database and collection like the below connection string

**mongodb://admin:admin@123@192.168.1.44:27017**

here
**1) admin after (//) is the username of the user
2) admin@123 after (:) is the password of user
3) 192.168.1.44 after (@) is the IP address of server
4) 27017 is the port number on which MongoDB is running**

Note: We need to refactor the @ symbol in the password using the regular expression for the validation of connection string.
for **@** symbol use **%40**
for **:** symbol use **%3A**